# Back button navigation closes my app on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I have an app and it works as expected on Windows 10. But on Windows 10 Mobile, when user presses back button, application closes. In my back requested event handler I even commented out GoBack() method but app still closes.

```
private void MobileNavigationService_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        var navigationService = UnityConfiguration.Resolve<IMobileNavigationService>();

        if (navigationService.CanGoBack())
        {
            //navigationService.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

I have a feeling that even though I set *e.Handled = true* it ignores it and acts like there is no handler.

**Updated**

As an additional information

App has only one page, Shell. it has common things like menu and title bar. It also has frame. In frame I open all the other pages. So going back, for my app, means going back in that frame, not in entire application. I want to override default behavior.

Comment: It's the default behavior. What do you expect?

Comment: Yeah, but default behavior must be overridden when *e.Hnalded* is set tu true. [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.systemnavigationmanager.aspx)

Comment: I believe the app doesn't actually close - it simply switches to the start screen, but the app continues in the background. It's what users expect to happen.

Comment: It is not what I expect to be happen. Actually I will navigate it back to previous page.

Comment: Oh, so you mean it happens when you're not on the bottom page in the back stack?

Comment: I just added some additional information about my application logic.

Comment: What's the implementation of `IMobileNavigationService`? I think it must be something in the code you're not showing. This sample Prism/Unity app does it with no special code: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Windows/tree/master/SplitViewSample

Comment: When I am commenting out If statement all together nothing is changed. So it is not because of *IMobileNavigationService* implementation. Thanks for sample I will take a look.

Comment: This app uses default behavior. this were not help at all.

Answer (score -1):

- Setting up an event handler for BackRequested and to navigate back in the page stack.
- Enabling and disabling the title bar back button based on the app's internal page stack.

You can get this DEMO from Microsoft in GitHub

[Back Button Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackButton)

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        bool optedIn = false;

        if ((bool)e.Parameter)
        {
            optedIn = true;

        }

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack && optedIn)
        {
            // If we have pages in our in-app backstack and have opted in to showing back, do so
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            // Remove the UI from the title bar if there are no pages in our in-app back stack
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Update with Source Code